# How can I make my CSS work only if a span is inside an <a> that does not have a class of "folder"?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have the following HTML:

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <span class="toggle"></span>
      <a class="folder">
         <span>Background</span>
      </a>
      <ul>
         <li>
            <a data-href="/C">
                <span>History</span>
            </a>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

I am using the following CSS to make the cursor into a pointer:

```
ul li span {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Is there a way I can modify this so that it does NOT change into a pointer if the `<span>` is inside an `<a>` that has a class of folder?

Comment: .folder a { cursor: default !important; } will work for all browsers and anywhere, not matter it's inside li, span, or a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use `:not()` here...

```
ul li a:not(.folder) span {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Since you also have `<span>` elements occurring inside `<li>` but outside `<a>`, you will need to modify the selector a bit...

```
ul li > span, ul li > a:not(.folder) > span {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Alternatively (or if you need to support browsers that don't understand `:not()`), just override it:

```
ul li span {
    cursor: pointer;
}

ul li a.folder span {
    cursor: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add one more rule **after** your existing rule:

```css
​ul li a.folder span {
    cursor:initial;
}​
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ctapx/)

Note that `initial` is not quite "standard", so you may want to use e.g. `default` or `auto`;

Comment: @BoltClock I know, just giving some idea. OP should know what cursor he wants.

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS also:

```
ul li a span{
cursor: default;
```

}

Check it in http://fiddle.jshell.net/5w2SX/

Answer (score -1):

below CSS with work for all browsers

```
.folder a {
 cursor: default !important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
ul li a span {
    cursor: pointer;
}

ul li a.folder span {
    cursor: default;
}
```

first part will convert cursor on elements "ul li a span" into pointer.

second line defines the exceptions, where all with class folder will have default cursor.

Comment: Except the OP doesn't just want any span inside any a.